# How to get lower function working to find string in list

Tags: python

I'm a student learning python and am currently working on an assignment for my class. I am running into a problem with trying to use the lower function to find user input string in a list. Here's the code so far

```
#Create list of fruits
fruits = ['banana' , 'apple' , 'orange' , 'kiwi' , 'pineapple', 'peach', 'papaya']

#Welcome user and explain fruit finder
welcome = "Welcome to the fruit finder program, please enter your name: "
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: ')

#Check if input matches fruit list and display the number of fruits to user
if sentence.lower() in fruits:
print("Here are the fruits found in your sentence: ")
else:
print(input('Fruit not found in sentence. Please try again: '))
```

The output I get is as follows:

> Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: Banana Kiwi Pineapple
> Fruit not found in sentence. Please try again:

Comment: Your current example will look for the entire sentence `banana kiwi pineapple`, which isn't in the `fruits` list.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that some indentation is off you need to:

- split the `input`, probably by space `" "` as the separator
- lower each word in the input
- iterate over words

Here's the example if you want to print them one by one if not you can aggregate the results in a `list`, `set`, `dictionary` (to assign counts as well), whatever you need.

```py
#Create list of fruits
fruits = ['banana' , 'apple' , 'orange' , 'kiwi' , 'pineapple', 'peach', 'papaya']

#Welcome user and explain fruit finder
welcome = "Welcome to the fruit finder program, please enter your name: "
words = [word.lower() for word in input('Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: ').split(" ")]

#Check if input matches fruit list and display the number of fruits to user
counter = 0
for word in words:
    if word in fruits:
        counter += 1
        print(f"{word} fruit found in your sentence")

print(f"A total of {counter} fruits found in your sentence")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're checking if the entire input sentence is in the fruits `list` using `sentence.lower()` in fruits. This condition checks if the entire sentence, including spaces and capitalization, is present in the list.

To find individual fruits within the sentence, you need to split the sentence into words and then check if each word (in lowercase) is in the fruits `list`. Here is how you can do this.

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'peach', 'papaya']

welcome = "Welcome to the fruit finder program, please enter your name: "
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: ')

sentence_words = sentence.lower().split()

found_fruits = []

for word in sentence_words:
    if word in fruits:
        found_fruits.append(word)

if found_fruits:
    print("Here are the fruits found in your sentence:", ", ".join(found_fruits))
else:
    print("No fruits found in the sentence.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current example will look for the entire sentence `banana kiwi pineapple`, which isn't in the `fruits` list.

You need to search per word. You can do this using `split` and a for loop.

```
for word in sentence.split():
    if word.lower() in fruits:
        print(f"{word} is a fruit")
```

Answer (score 0):

As your list of fruits is lowercase you should also normalise the user input to the same case.

Having said that, a set would be more appropriate.

Then split the input sentence into individual words.

Use the built-in *filter()* function to identify the words in the sentence you're interested in - i.e., the fruits.

Something like this:

```
fruits = {'banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'peach', 'papaya', 'tomato'}

sentence = input('Please enter a sentence containing the name of a fruit: ')

if found := list(filter(lambda word: word in fruits, sentence.lower().split())):
    print('I found the following fruit(s):', *found)
else:
    print('No fruits found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input into a list of word to check with fruit list. You can use intersection set method to get the same value of the lists. Also, use while loop to re-ask the user for input if intersection method return none or empty:

```
fruits = ['banana' , 'apple' , 'orange' , 'kiwi' , 'pineapple', 'peach', 'papaya']

sentence = input('Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: ')

while True:
    if found := set(fruits).intersection(sentence.lower().split()):
        print(f"Here are the fruits found in your sentence:", *found, sep='\n')
        break
    else:
        sentence = input('Fruit not found in sentence. Please try again: ')

# Please enter a sentence with fruit in it to begin: Strawberry Grape Melon
# Fruit not found in sentence. Please try again: Banana Kiwi Pineapple Grape Melon
# Here are the fruits found in your sentence:
# kiwi
# pineapple
# banana
```